# Django: TypeError - bad operand type for unary -: 'str'

Tags: python, django

I am using this line of code in my views:

```
prev_articles = Article.objects.all().order_by(-'created')[1:4]
```

and it is giving me an error:

```
Exception Value:    
bad operand type for unary -: 'str'
```

Last I checked this code seemed to work on another project of my peers, what am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is `(-'created')` supposed to do?

Comment: try `order_by('-created')`, minus is misplaced

Comment: Thank you andrea.ge, I knew it was something petty. Much appreciated!

Comment: @mhlester: -created means descending order by created field

Comment: yup i figured something like that, but definitely not -'created'